# Form validation not working

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having real trouble with Code Igniter. I have tried to enable errors which displays nothing useful and as far as I am aware, I am following the docs correctly. The problem I am having is that the validation_errors() function in the template does not echo validation problems. The validation process is working (it returns to the form if validation fails) however no error message is shown.
 I have however included the method from the controller below and view form as well.

$this->load->model('admin_members','members', TRUE);
      if(  $this->input->post('addmember')){

```
         $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // Displaying Errors In Div
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

        // Validation For Name Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mname', 'Member Name', 'required|min_length[15]|max_length[25]');
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        // Validation For Email Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        if($this->validation->run()== FALSE){
            $this->load->view('admin/member-management/add', $data);

        }

        else{
                $member_id = $this->members->add();

        if(!is_dir('images/members/' . $member_id )) mkdir('images/members/' . $member_id , 0777, TRUE);

        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/members/' . $member_id ."/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '22222';
        $config['max_width']  = '10242';
        $config['max_height']  = '10242';
        $config['file_name']  = "profile.jpg" ;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('profile_image');

        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/members/' . $member_id ."/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '22222';
        $config['max_width']  = '10242';
        $config['max_height']  = '10242';
        $config['file_name']  = "pan_card.jpg" ;    
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('pan_card');

        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/members/' . $member_id ."/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '22222';
        $config['max_width']  = '10242';
        $config['max_height']  = '10242';
        $config['file_name']  = "id_proof.jpg" ;    
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('id_proof');

        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/members/' . $member_id ."/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '22222';
        $config['max_width']  = '10242';
        $config['max_height']  = '10242';
        $config['file_name']  = "add_proof.jpg" ;   
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('add_proof');

        redirect('admin_member', 'refresh');

  }

}
```

view/admin_member/add.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$this->validation->run() == FALSE
```

To

```
$this->form_validation->run() === FALSE
```

please correct your syntax of checking form validation rules in your controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to echo validation errors, `<?php echo validation_errors()?>` in the view that the form must return to.
In your code also, you passed the variable `$data` that I noticed was not declared anywhere else in the code. I assume that either `$data` is a array which will hold some variables for the view or `$data` you assumed has the values of what you passed to the server. In this case you can use `<?php echo set_values(//Value of the name parameter you give to the input)`. This can be useful if you want to return to the form but do not want to fill it again.
As an added bonus Use `$this-form_validation->run() === FALSE` instead of `$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE`. This won't fix the problem but it ensures that if an attacker changes the return type of the element to string, the string "TRUE" won't be evaluated to `TRUE`.

Lemme know if I have answered your question...:)